# Protect Web pages using password or authentication service

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, password-protection, netlify

I would like to know if there is a way to password protect web pages developed with simple HTML/ javascript.

I am hosting the web page on netlify and I have also tried hosting on Firebase and it is working from both ends but I do not want anyone with a link to be able to view and use the website.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this with Firebase, but Netlify does allows for site-wide passwords (with the caveat that you have to pay for their Pro service, [as per their pricing page](https://www.netlify.com/pricing/)). If this is truly important enough that you need to password protect your pages, it's probably worth it.

Comment: I have ended up using firebase authentication to check on each page if the user is not logged in to redirect to the login page. while this might not be the best way, I did not know of any other way and this works for me.